# Need help with wiring up a switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a single gang box with 3 pieces of romex in it one is a homerun"hot", the other is a switch leg, and the last one is for the receptacles in the room how do i hook it all up to a single pole switch to where my receptacles stay hot when the switch is off?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we can only guess without a picture

Comment: tie all the hots together with a pig tail to the switch.

Answer (score 1):

All the whites(neutrals) wire nut or other type of wire connection together.

Homerun(from panel) hot to black receptacles and a short black for switch together.

Black of switch leg to other switch screw.

All grounds together, if metal box then add to ground screw of box.  If plastic box then to ground screw of switch.

This assumes the light or something is only powered by the homerun in the switch.

Comment: To the downvoter,  If I made a mistake or left important information out or even totally wrong, would be nice to have that information.  I know I do not know everything, but do like to learn.

Comment: Looks about right to me, I too would like to know why the DV